# How do I configure my Twig / Symfony2 services for this?

Tags: symfony, twig

How do I configure my services for this?

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/RoutingExtension.php

I'm guessing it's something like this:

```
  twig.extension.anyName:
    class: Bundle\Twig\RoutingExtension
    arguments:
      - "twig.extension.routing"
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

...but it errors with:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Bundle\Twig\RoutingExtension::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface, string given...
```

Comment: It seems that your function wants something that implements `UrlGeneratorInterface`. What exactly are you looking for and how is the class you linked relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid syntax for referencing other services is @ symbol followed by service name. Currently you are passing string "twig.extension.routing" to your service constructor.

If you want pass service instance to your service, it could look something like this

```
 twig.extension.anyName:
    class: Bundle\Twig\RoutingExtension
    arguments:
      - "@twig.extension.routing"
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: Thats because service @twig.extension.routing does not implement required interface. I guess what you are looking for is router service (@router)...